# fullcalendar v4 external drop events

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I am using the v4 Alpha version of fullcalendar which has had jQuery removed, the only examples I can find for drag external events are related to v3 or earlier which uses jQuery.  Does anyone have any examples of external drag with v4 Alpha

I have followed as best I can the example [here](https://codepen.io/pen/):

```
<div id="external-events">
  <div class="fc-event" ngDraggable [zIndex]="99999" [zIndexMoving]="99999" [trackPosition]="false" style="margin: 1em 0; padding: .5em; cursor: move;"
  *ngFor="let event of externalEvents" [attr.data-event]="event">An Event</div>
</div>
```

Each event in the `externalEvents` array is a valid json object

```
externalEvents = [
  {
    'title': 'Some Event',
    'duration': '00:30:00'
  },
  {
    'title': 'Some Other Event'
  }
]
```

My events are draggable but not reflecting anything when dragged over the calendar control, nothing visual and the `drop` event is not fired (my code can be found in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fullcalendar-schedule))

Does anyone have a working example using fullcalendar v4 Alpha please

Answer (score 3):

Dont like to answer my own questions but I have figured this out now, I was missing an additional script import that fullcalendar v4 uses for drag/drop, the component is essentially using `dragula` and I had not imported the `dragula` or `fullcalendar-dragula` scripts.

For anyone stumbling across this you can find a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fullcalendar-schedule)

Comment: Thx Neil for info and stackblitz example. But unfortunately I'm not able to setup this "external drop events" on my local: fresh Angular 11 project. I'm getting FullCalendar is not defined > both lines where FC is used throws errors (FullCalendar.dragula & ullCalendar.Calendar) What does mean these declaration: declare const FullCalendar? And what is "fullcalendar-dragula" script? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Nice work Neil!  In order to save some time here is what I added to my angular.json file for to get it to work.  If you don't need scheduler you can remove the last css and js entries.

```
 "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.min.css",
          "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
          "node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
          "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
          "node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.min.js",
          "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js",
          "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/dragula.min.js"
          "node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.min.js"

  ]
```